# Opengl Vertex attribute stride

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl-es, rendering

Hey.
I new to OpenGL ES but I've had my share of experience with normal OpenGL.
I've been told that using interlaced arrays for the vertex buffers is a lot faster due to the optimisation for avoiding cache misses.
I've developed a vertex format that I will use that looks like this

```
struct SVertex
{
    float x,y,z;
    float nx,ny,nz;
    float tx,ty,tz;
    float bx,by,bz;
    float tu1,tv1;
    float tu2,tv2;
};
```

Then I used "glVertexAttribPointer(index,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,stride,v);" to point to the vertex array. The index is the one of the attribute I want to use and everything else is ok except the stride. It worked before I decided to add this into the equation. I passed the stride both as sizeof(SVertex) and like 13*4 but none of them seem to work.
If it has any importance I draw the primitives like this

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,surface->GetIndexCount()/3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,surface->IndPtr());
```

In the OpenGL specs it's written that the stride should be the size in bytes from the end of the attribute( in this case z) to the next attribute of the same kind(in this case x). So by my calculations this should be 13(nx,ny,nz,tx,ty....tuv2,tv2) times 4 (the size of a float).
Oh and one more thing is that the display is just empty.
Could anyone please help me with this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I said 13 values thinking I have to substract the first 3(if you have just x,y,z then stride is 0);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a structure like this, then `stride` is just `sizeof SVertex` and it's the same for every attribute. There's nothing complicated here.

If this didn't work, look for your error somewhere else.

For example here:

`surface->GetIndexCount()/3`

This parameter should be *the number of **vertices, not primitives*** to be sent - hence I'd say that this division by three is wrong. Leave it as:

`surface->GetIndexCount()`

Comment: Thanks. It was the index count. Although if you look at Ogl specs "
count-Specifies the number of elements to be rendered."

Comment: I believe that the spec means that an "element" is same as "vertex" in this context. Lines, triangles, quads, polygons, etc are together referred to as "primitives".

Comment: actually second argument is the number of **indices, not vertices**. About the specs "element" means more *primitives build with indices according a topology mode*. But at the end of the day it's simply the indices count.

Comment: 1 index usually corresponds to 1 vertex, so that's not really a big difference imho :) But yes, there are cases when this doesn't hold (primitive restart, instancing...).

Comment: You can have a VBO with 1024 vertices and draw only 10 indices from it using an indexed draw call. That's what I mean. But yes I understand your point, an index always corresponds to a vertex, hopefully ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Then I used
>   "glVertexAttribPointer(index,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,stride,v);"
>   to point to the vertex array. The
>   index is the one of the attribute I
>   want to use and everything else is ok
>   except the stride

This does not work for texcoord (you have 2x 2 floats or 1x 4 floats).

About the stride, like Kos said, I think you should pass a stride of `16 * sizeof(float)` (the size of your `SVertex`).

Also another thing worth mentioning. You say you want to optimize for performance. Why dont you compress your vertex to the max, and suppress redundant values? This would save a lot of bandwidth.

`x, y, z` are OK, but `nx` and `ny` are self sufficient if your normals are normalized (which may be the case). You can extract in the vertex shader `nz` (assuming you have shader capabilities). The same thing applies for `tx` and `ty`. You don't need `bx, by, bz` at all since you know it's the cross product of `normal` and `tangent`.

```
struct SPackedVertex
{
    float x,y,z,w;       //pack all on vector4
    float nx,ny,tx,ty;
    float tu1,tv1;tu2,tv2;
};
```

Comment: Some good remarks here about the redundancy, but does this normal packing result in really improved performance? Sounds likely (the gpu memory latency is probably a tighter bottleneck than vertex processing power in most cases), but do the benchmarks actually confirm it?

Comment: I don't know, just guessing here. Like always, benchmark, benchmark, benchmark! :) If OP is using OGL ES, his code probably runs on handheld devices which are far in terms of memory bandwidth from desktop GPUs (I think), so it may be worth trying..

Comment: Also I don't know if this can be apply here, but size of vertex also seems to matter for pre-VS cache (maybe 32 or 64 bytes is better than 48..) In that case I would try to compress even further, to 32 bytes. This could be done by using half float (GL_OES_vertex_half_float) for normals, tangents and texcoords: http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/GDC06-ATI_Session-Zarge-PerfTools.pdf

Comment: Thank you for you sugestions. I will try to take them into account.

Comment: Nice. Half float seems to be already a part of OpenGL 3.1, btw.